# OAuth 2.0 not working with the new Envato API

Tags: php, json, curl, oauth-2.0

Hey i am just a learner in CURL, and i am learning through this new Envato
API. I don't know what mistake i'm making, I can get the code but cannot call using the POST method in https://build.envato.com/api#oauth

```
$ch = curl_init();

$url = 'https://api.envato.com/tokengrant_type=authorization_code&code='$_GET["code"]'&client_id=1&client_secret=MYSECRETKEY?type=post';

//makes the array suitable for sending
$items = http_build_query($member);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, count($members));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $items);

//execute
$result = curl_exec($ch);

//close curl session / free resources
curl_close($ch);


//ends
```

`

Answer (score 1):

You're using an undefined variable `$member` i.e. an undefined value to fill out the POST body. Moreover, the parameters that you include a query parameters in the URL should really be a part of the POST body. This should work:

```
$ch = curl_init('https://api.envato.com/token');

$member = array(
  'grant_type' => 'authorization_code',
  'code' => $_GET["code"],
  'client_id' => "1",
  'client_secret' => 'MYSECRETKEY'
);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, True);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($member));

$result = curl_exec($ch);    
curl_close($ch);
```

Comment: if it worked then please accept and perhaps upvote the answer